# Restore IMEI for Samsung Galaxy SL (GT-I9003) when there is no backup

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sim-card, imei, samsung-galaxy-sl

Well I was on phone and suddenly I lost IMEI and my SIM card is not detected.
So I tried flashing (to some firmware and I flashed back to original I9003XWKPG) and nothing.

I don't have any backups. I have Samsung Galaxy SL (GT-I9003).

How can I restore my IMEI?

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: IMEI BLANK] [image: IMG: PHONE INFO]

Comment: *Comment by [user90492](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/134749/user90492) (lacking the rep):* If your device is rooted, get an app called root explorer and go to `/system/efs` and see if your imei is in there.

Comment: *Comment by myself:* Please check [these search results from our site](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=samsung+restore+imei+answers%3A1) :)

Answer (score -1):

Were you messing around with poweruser settings because most of us don't suddenly "lose IMEI"  but in that case if you are rooted get an app called root explorer and go to the following directory /system/efs and see if your imei is in there. otherwise you will have to buy a new phone.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! This is a question-and-answer site, [not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107/192154): please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://android.stackexchange.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.